# Apache-POI not saving excel workbook even after doing fileoutputstream.close()

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am trying to generate new excel files based on a common template. I am opening the template excel file, editing it and saving it in a new location. To write the file I am using FileOutputStream and i am closing the stream after writing to save it. The entire process works correctly, but the newly created excel file is not saved properly. My template file is of 35kb and my newly created excel file shows 30kb only. When I open the newly created excel file, I can see the data written, and I need to save it and close it to reflect the correct size of 36kb.
The new excels are required to be uploaded to an external application which shows "no data found" when directly uploading the 30kb, unsaved excel whereas the 36kb saved file successfully uploads the file.

I tried various different ways suggested on internet to do the same thing and none of them are generating proper excel files. I am using java 1.7 and apache-poi version 3.17.

Following is a sample of my code:-

```
public void createExcelFiles() throws ParseException, IOException {

    File file = new File(ExcelTemplatePath);
    FileInputStream fip = new FileInputStream(file);
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(excelOutputFile);

    XSSFWorkbook workbookOld = new XSSFWorkbook(fip);
    try (SXSSFWorkbook workbook = new SXSSFWorkbook(workbookOld, rowAccessWindowSize)) {

        if (makeLargeFiles) {
            SXSSFSheet sheet = (SXSSFSheet) workbook.getSheetAt(0);
            makeExcelFile.makeLargeFile(sheet);
            workbook.write(fos);
        } else {
            Sheet sheet = workbookOld.getSheetAt(0);
            makeExcelFile.makeNormalFile(sheet);
            workbookOld.write(fos);

        }
        fos.close();
        fip.close();
        workbook.close();
    }
    workbookOld.close();

}
```

Comment: First close workbook, after that close Input and Output streams

Comment: I tried that also, with the same result.

Comment: You are trying to close the workbook 2 times. Once through `try-with-resource` and once manually. Move `fos.close()` and `fip.close()` out of the try block and remove `workbook.close();`

Comment: I don't believe the problem is because of not closing streams. `Apache poi` stores its files according to minimum requirements of the file systems. This is not the same as `Excel` does. `Excel` stores additional optional elements in the files. And your external application which shows "no data found" seems insisting on this additional optional elements. So you needs determining what exactly is the 8 kByte difference between file saved by `apache poi` and file saved by `Excel`. Maybe you can upload both, so we can check?

Answer (score 0):

Wrapped I/O streams like `XSSFWorkbook` should close first, possibly still writing an epilogue to the wrapped OutputStream. And the the low-level stream may be closed.

Mind, that some wrapping classes will close the wrapped stream themselves inside their own `close`.

As try-with-resources is ideal, to also close in case of an exception, the final version would be:

```
public void createExcelFiles() throws ParseException, IOException {
    File file = new File(ExcelTemplatePath);
    try (FileInputStream fip = new FileInputStream(file);
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(excelOutputFile);
            XSSFWorkbook workbookOld = new XSSFWorkbook(fip);
            SXSSFWorkbook workbook = new SXSSFWorkbook(workbookOld, rowAccessWindowSize)) {

        if (makeLargeFiles) {
            SXSSFSheet sheet = (SXSSFSheet) workbook.getSheetAt(0);
            makeExcelFile.makeLargeFile(sheet);
            workbook.write(fos);
        } else {
            Sheet sheet = workbookOld.getSheetAt(0);
            makeExcelFile.makeNormalFile(sheet);
            workbookOld.write(fos);

        }
    }
    // Doing in reverse order of declaration:
    // 1. workbook.close();
    // 2. workbookOld.close();
    // 3. fos.close();
    // 4. fip.close();
}
```

In your code there was a reversal, and close happened explicit and via try-with-resources.

Comment: Maybe it depends on `makeLargeFiles` (check value, try both cases). For large files SXSSFWorkbook or not. Try not using SXSSFWorkbook when `!makeLargeFiles`. `workbookOld.write(fos)` seems to go wrong, as `fos.close()` happens to early; will change the answer. **fos now opened earlier.**

Answer (score 0):

The issue was resolved using by shared string property of excel. I updated the workbook constructor call as below:

SXSSFWorkbook workbook = new SXSSFWorkbook(workbookOld, rowAccessWindowSize, true, true)

The second true parameter is for the use of shared strings. Using this property makes the data visible to the external application without the need to open and save it again. However the size issue still remains and why the use of shared string works is still unclear.
For more info on shared string check [this](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xssf/model/SharedStringsTable.html) out.